# Parsing Non Standard JSON in Angular Js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am getting a JSON response from a Restful service in the following format,

```
{
   "comments":{
      "columns":[
         "clientId",
         "treatmentDate",
         "comments",
         "photo",
         "practitioner"
      ],
      "records":[
         [
            "1",
            "2016-09-12",
            "Some Coments",
            "0",
            "Doc 4"
         ],
         [
            "1",
            "2016-09-11",
            "DDD oNE",
            "1",
            "Docc 3"
         ]
      ]
   }
}
```

Record is starting with table name and separate arrays of columns and records follows. Angular is not accepting data is this format. However if I provide  data with standard format as follows, it works perfectly.

```
[
   {
      "clientId":"1",
      "treatmentDate":"2016-09-12",
      "comments":"Some Coments",
      "photo":"0",
      "practitioner":"Doc 4"
   },
   {
      "clientId":"1",
      "treatmentDate":"2016-09-11",
      "comments":"DDD oNE",
      "photo":"1",
      "practitioner":"Docc 3"
   }
]
```

Is there a directive that can do this for me or shall I create a custom function, any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like you'll have to write a custom function to map the first array (columns) to the second array (records). A couple loops and you're good

Comment: The json is valid. So what do you mean by "Angular is not accepting data is this format"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason you cannot just manually reshape the data to conform the form you expect?

```
var data = json.comments.records.map(function(record) {
    return json.comments.columns.reduce(function(reshaped, columnName, idx) {
        reshaped[columnName] = record[idx];
        return reshaped;
    }, {});
});
```

Be careful with this though; this expects the length of each of the arrays in `records` to always be the same as the number of column names.

Comment: Thanks it work nicely as the numbers remain same always. I learn some new things today.